Unable to connect two Django models
I'm building a forum website and I have the following models:
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,     related_name='profile', null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)
    football_club = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    userprofile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile',    null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    post_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

   
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

The CustomUser fields are entered during the sign-up, while the Profile fields are supposed to be optionally edited on the /profile page of the website.
The forms for both models are represented as
{{ form.as_p }} 

inside the corresponding html files.
Both forms are setup inside the forms.py file:
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser, Profile

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['avatar', 'football_club', 'location']

And I have the following function/class inside my views.py file:
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login'))

@login_required
def profile(request):
    profile = request.user.userprofile
    print("Profile: ", profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {'form': form})

But the two models are not actually linked with each other. I have tried the following in one of my html template pages:
<ul>
    <li><h3>{{ post.author.username }}</h3></li>
    <li>Posts: {{ post.author.post_count }}</li>
    <li>Club: {{ post.author.userprofile.football_club }}</li>
</ul>

And I'm getting the username and post_count displayed correctly, but the Club field remains empty, although the football_club and locations are being stored into the database.
I've tried to edit already existing football_club and location fields inside the profile.html, but instead editing, it just creates another model instance in the database.
Also, inside python shell I've tried the following:
>>> from accounts.models import Profile, CustomUser
>>> lastprofile = Profile.objects.last()
>>> print(lastprofile.football_club)
Inter
>>> print(lastprofile.location)
Milan
>>> print(lastprofile.user)
None


Use the OneToOneField in one direction.

I also don't see how you pass two forms to the template: it seems you only pass one form.

It is also a bit bizarre to have both a Profile and a CustomUser: normally you make a custom user exactly to prevent this: making an extra model where you thus have a lot of looking through ForeignKey/OneToOneFields.

It is bizarre to have both a CustomUser and a Profile. Normally if you want to customize the user modeling, you either make a user model yourself, with all the (optional and required) data, or if you don't want to hook in a custom User model, you work with a Profile to store the additional (often optional) data, but usually you don't do both: this is often the worst of both worlds, since then you have to implement custom logic to create and log in users, but also have to look through ForeignKeys or OneToOneFields for the other data. To make matters even worse, these two models seem to have each a OneToOneField linking to each other. Usually you write one OneToOneField, and thus use the relation in reverse.
I think in this specific case, it is better to stick to one model, and thus move the fields from Profile to CustomUser, and make these blank=True [Django-doc], this makes the fields optional:
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    post_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)
    football_club = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
Then the form is simplified to:
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from django import forms


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'avatar', 'football_club', 'location']
and the Profile can just make a subset of the fields:
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['avatar', 'football_club', 'location']


@login_required
def profile(request):
    profile = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {'form': form})
We thus don't need to define values for the OneToOneField, and definitely don't need to link these bi-directionally. Performance will typically also be better, since it does not require extra querying to fetch the .location, .avatar, etc. of the user.


Note: Django's DateTimeField [Django-doc]
has a auto_now_add=… parameter [Django-doc]
to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (editable=False), such
that it does not appear in ModelForms by default.



Note: Please don't store aggregates in the model: determine aggregates when needed: storing aggregates in the model makes updating and keeping data in sync harder.

